# Rails associations doesn't save to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, model-associations

I have this set up, but noting gets saved to the db when I try to save a practitioner.
The tables are users, clinics and practitioners. The user should be able to create multiple clinics and each clinic should be able to add multiple practitioners to the specific clinic.

I get this error from the log

```
Started PUT "/registration_steps/practitioners_general" for ::1 at 2020-03-01 11:59:29 +0100
Processing by RegistrationStepsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KGwLxzNk96QEiY8Enun4cK3Gd3ec0GFsJxFxIq75MDQEGVcpapxTfh7aHR6slMojd3+hQg4MevmPDewRq7vGiA==", "user"=>{"clinics_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"practitioners_attributes"=>{"1583060279301"=>{"practitioner_first_name"=>"sdsad", "practitioner_last_name"=>"sdsadsa", "practitioner_description"=>"sadasda", "practitioner_mail"=>"kvnirvana@yahoo.dk", "practitioner_phone"=>"24210886", "practitioner_website"=>""}}, "id"=>"7"}}}, "commit"=>"Gem", "id"=>"practitioners_general"}
  User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 95 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/registration_steps_controller.rb:17
Unpermitted parameter: :practitioners_attributes
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/registration_steps_controller.rb:19
  Clinic Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `clinics`.* FROM `clinics` WHERE `clinics`.`user_id` = 95 AND `clinics`.`id` = 7
  ↳ app/controllers/registration_steps_controller.rb:19
   (1.4ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/registration_steps_controller.rb:19
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/registration_steps_controller.rb:20
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/registration_steps_controller.rb:20
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/registration_steps/practitioners_professions
Completed 302 Found in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 5.1ms)


Started GET "/registration_steps/practitioners_professions" for ::1 at 2020-03-01 11:59:29 +0100
Processing by RegistrationStepsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"practitioners_professions"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 95 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/registration_steps_controller.rb:12
  Rendering registration_steps/practitioners_professions.html.erb within layouts/application
  Profession Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `professions`.* FROM `professions` INNER JOIN `user_professions` ON `professions`.`id` = `user_professions`.`profession_id` WHERE `user_professions`.`user_id` = 95
  ↳ app/views/registration_steps/practitioners_professions.html.erb:47
  Profession Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `professions`.* FROM `professions`
  ↳ app/views/registration_steps/practitioners_professions.html.erb:47
  Speciality Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `specialities`.* FROM `specialities` INNER JOIN `user_specialities` ON `specialities`.`id` = `user_specialities`.`speciality_id` WHERE `user_specialities`.`user_id` = 95
  ↳ app/views/registration_steps/practitioners_professions.html.erb:62
  Speciality Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `specialities`.* FROM `specialities`
  ↳ app/views/registration_steps/practitioners_professions.html.erb:62
  Service Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `services`.* FROM `services` WHERE `services`.`user_id` = 95
  ↳ app/views/registration_steps/practitioners_professions.html.erb:81
  Rendered services/_services_fields.html.erb (7.5ms)
  Rendered services/_services_fields.html.erb (6.4ms)
  Rendered registration_steps/practitioners_professions.html.erb within layouts/application (34.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 92ms (Views: 88.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

This is how I have tried to make it work so far:

User has many clinics
clinics belongs to user

clinics has many practitioners
practitioners belongs to clinics

I’ve added a foreign user key to connect clinics table with users table

I’ve added a foreign clinic key to connect practitioners table with clinics table

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord        
has_many :clinics, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :clinics, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**clinic.rb**

```
class Clinic < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :practitioners
accepts_nested_attributes_for :practitioners, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

**practitioner.rb**

```
class Practitioner < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to: clinic
end
```

**add clinics foreign key to practitioners**

```
class AddClinicReferenceToPratitioners < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
def change
add_reference :practitioners, :clinic, foreign_key: true
end
end
```

**add users foreign key to clinics**

```
class AddUserReferenceToClinics < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
def change
add_reference :clinics, :user, foreign_key: true
end
end
```

**practitioners_general.html.rb**

```
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content practitioner">
            <h2 class="page-title">Generel information</h2>
            <%= simple_form_for @user, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>
                <%= f.simple_fields_for(:clinics) do |p| %>
                    <%= render 'clinics/clinics_fields', :f => p %>
                <% end %>

                <div class="submit-container">
                    <%= f.submit "Gem", :class => 'btn blue' %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**clinics/_clinics_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for(:practitioners) do |p| %>
<%= render 'practitioners/practitioners_fields', :f => p %>
<% end %>
<div class="links">
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Practitioner', f, :practitioners, :partial => 'practitioners/practitioners_fields' %>
</div>
```

**practitioners/practitioners_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="basic-section">

    <div class="info-group">
      <div class="field-group">
        <div class="field text-field">

          <%= f.input_field :practitioner_first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "Fornavn", placeholder: "Fornavn" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field text-field">
          <%= f.input_field :practitioner_last_name, required: true, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "Efternavn", placeholder: "Efternavn" %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about-section">
    <div class="field text-field">
      <%= f.input_field :practitioner_description, :as => :text, :input_html => { 'rows' => 5}, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "Beskrivelse af behandler", placeholder: "Beskrivelse af behandler" %>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="field-group contact-section">
    <div class="field text-field">
      <%= f.input_field :practitioner_mail, input_html: { autocomplete: 'email' }, autofocus: true, placeholder: "E-mail" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field text-field">
      <%= f.input_field :practitioner_phone, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "Tlf. nr.", placeholder: "Tlf. nr." %>
    </div>
    <div class="field text-field">
      <%= f.input_field :practitioner_website, required: false, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "Hjemmeside", placeholder: "Hjemmeside" %>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**registration_steps_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationStepsController < ApplicationController

    include Wicked::Wizard
    steps :company_general, :company_images, :practitioners_general, :practitioners_professions, :practitioners_educations

    def create
      @practitioner = Practitioner.new(params[:practitioners])
      @practitioner.save
    end

    def show
     @user = current_user    
    render_wizard 
    end

    def update
      @user = current_user
      # Change @user.attributes(user_params) by @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      render_wizard @user
    end



private
def user_params
  params.require(:user)
  .permit(:gender, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone, 
    :clinic_logo, 
    :practitioner_image,
    :public_health_insurance, 
    clinic_images: [], 
    profession_ids: [], 
    speciality_ids: [], 
    services_attributes: [:id, :description, :name, :duration, :price, :_destroy], 
    educations_attributes: [:id, :name, :place, :year, :_destroy],
    membership_ids: [],
    awards_attributes: [:id, :name, :year, :_destroy],
    clinics_attributes: [:id, :clinic_logo, :clinic_name, :clinic_address, :clinic_zip_code, :clinic_municipality, :clinic_about, :clinic_mail, :clinic_phone, :clinic_website, :clinic_city, :_destroy],
    practitioners_attributes: [:id, :practitioner_first_name, :practitioner_last_name, :practitioner_description, :practitioner_mail, :practitioner_phone, :practitioner_website, :_destroy])

end

end
```

**ApplicationController.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    before_action :authenticate_user!, :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: 
        [:gender, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone, 
        :clinic_logo, 
        :practitioner_image,
        :public_health_insurance, 
        clinic_images: [], 
        profession_ids: [], 
        speciality_ids: [], 
        services_attributes: [:id, :description, :name, :duration, :price, :_destroy], 
        educations_attributes: [:id, :name, :place, :year, :_destroy],
        membership_ids: [],
        awards_attributes: [:id, :name, :year, :_destroy],
        clinics_attributes: [:id, :clinic_logo, :clinic_name, :clinic_address, :clinic_zip_code, :clinic_municipality, :clinic_about, :clinic_mail, :clinic_phone, :clinic_website, :clinic_city, :_destroy],
        practitioners_attributes: [:id, :practitioner_first_name, :practitioner_last_name, :practitioner_description, :practitioner_mail, :practitioner_phone, :practitioner_website, :_destroy]])


        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: 
          [:gender, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone, 
            :clinic_logo, 
            :practitioner_image, 
            :public_health_insurance, 
            clinic_images: [], 
            profession_ids: [], 
            speciality_ids: [], 
            services_attributes: [:id, :description, :name, :duration, :price, :_destroy], 
            educations_attributes: [:id, :name, :place, :year, :_destroy],
            membership_ids: [],
            awards_attributes: [:id, :name, :year, :_destroy],
            clinics_attributes: [:id, :clinic_logo, :clinic_name, :clinic_address, :clinic_zip_code, :clinic_municipality, :clinic_about, :clinic_mail, :clinic_phone, :clinic_website, :clinic_city, :_destroy],
            practitioners_attributes: [:id, :practitioner_first_name, :practitioner_last_name, :practitioner_description, :practitioner_mail, :practitioner_phone, :practitioner_website, :_destroy]])



    end


    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      rails_admin_path
    end

  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

  devise_for :users, controllers: {:registrations => "users/registrations" 
  }

  resources :registration_steps
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'pages#index' 
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  get 'team', to: 'pages#team'
  get 'faqs', to: 'pages#faqs'
  get 'faqspractitioners', to: 'pages#faqspractitioners'
  get 'faqsusers', to: 'pages#faqsusers'
  get 'login', to: 'pages#login'
  get 'signup', to: 'pages#signup'
  get 'search', to: 'pages#search'


  get "userprofiles/user_info" => "userprofiles#user_info", as: "user_info"
  get "userprofiles/clinic_info" => "userprofiles#clinic_info", as: "clinic_info"
  get "userprofiles/practitioner_info" => "userprofiles#practitioner_info", as: "practitioner_info"


  patch "userprofiles/user_info" => "userprofiles#update"
  patch "userprofiles/clinic_info" => "userprofiles#update"
  patch "userprofiles/practitioner_info" => "userprofiles#update"




  devise_scope :user do 
    scope module: :users do
      resources :registrations, only: [] do
        member do
          delete :delete_image_attachment
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Please show relevant `create` code and server log output from dev console. Just showing view code and model associations isn't nearly enough.

Comment: I have updated the question with registration_steps_controller.rb where I have the create code and I have added the server log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the params from

```
    clinics_attributes: [:id, :clinic_logo, :clinic_name, :clinic_address, :clinic_zip_code, :clinic_municipality, :clinic_about, :clinic_mail, :clinic_phone, :clinic_website, :clinic_city, :_destroy],
        practitioners_attributes: [:id, :practitioner_first_name, :practitioner_last_name, :practitioner_description, :practitioner_mail, :practitioner_phone, :practitioner_website, :_destroy])

end
```

to

```
clinics_attributes: [:id, :clinic_logo, :clinic_name, :clinic_address, :clinic_zip_code, :clinic_municipality, :clinic_about, :clinic_mail, :clinic_phone, :clinic_website, :clinic_city, :_destroy,
    practitioners_attributes: [:id, :practitioner_first_name, :practitioner_last_name, :practitioner_description, :practitioner_mail, :practitioner_phone, :practitioner_website, :_destroy]])

end
```

Comment: thats correct, but you need to also understand he concept behind it. Just copy paste, hit and trial wont help in long run.

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :practitioners
```

...in your server log?

You have `Parameters` that look like this:

```
{
  "user"=>{
    "practitioners"=>{
      "practitioner_image"=>        #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f811c002dd8 ...>, 
      "practitioner_first_name"=>   "Kasper", 
      "practitioner_last_name"=>    "Valentin", 
      "gender"=>                    "Mand", 
      "practitioner_description"=>  "asasdas", 
      "public_health_insurance"     =>"1", 
      "practitioner_mail"           =>"kvnirvana@yahoo.dk", 
      "practitioner_phone"          =>"24210886", 
      "practitioner_website"        =>"www.yahoo.dk"
    }
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Gem", 
  "id"=>"practitioners_general"
}
```

In your `user_params`, you have this:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user)
  .permit(
    ...,
    practitioners_attributes: [
      :id, 
      :practitioner_first_name, 
      :practitioner_last_name, 
      :practitioner_description, 
      :practitioner_mail, 
      :practitioner_phone, 
      :practitioner_website, 
      :_destroy
    ]
  )
end
```

You see? You permit `practitioners_attributes`, but your `Parameters` has `practitioners`. Since you don't permit `practitioners`, it is rejected as an `Unpermitted parameter`, which is exactly what your log files tell you.

If you want to permit `practitioner_attributes`, then do something more like:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for(:practitioner_attributes) do |p| %>
  <%= render 'practitioners/practitioners_fields', :f => p %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to leave `practitioners` in your `Parameters`, then do something more like:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user)
  .permit(
    ...,
    practitioners: [
      :id, 
      :practitioner_first_name, 
      :practitioner_last_name, 
      :practitioner_description, 
      :practitioner_mail, 
      :practitioner_phone, 
      :practitioner_website, 
      :_destroy
    ]
  )
end
```

The point is, whatever is in your `Parameters` has to match what's in your `permit` statement. Right now, they do not match, so `practitioners` is an unpermitted parameter.

Comment: ok, I see, but I'm not sure how to make it work. Do I add gender, public_health_insurance and practitioner_image to the practitioners_attributes in the user params? Also should they be in the table called practitioners? at the moment gender and public_health_insurance are located in the user table while practitioner_image is made from the active storage gem

Comment: Your bigger problem right now is that what's in your `Parameters` (practitioners) doesn't match what's in your `permit` statement (practitioner_attributes). That's what's giving you the unpermitted parameters message. Your table structure is a whole different question.

Comment: ok, but if I remove the practitioners parameters from the form fields, that are not in my permit statement, I still get the unpermitted parameter error, but now they should match right? See the updated code.

Comment: Did you update the code? It still shows `<%= f.simple_fields_for(:practitioners) do |p| %>` and `.permit(..., practitioners_attributes: [..., ...])`. `practitioners` != `practitioners_attributes`.

Comment: In the updated code, I've just removed the fields from the form, that wasn't in the permit statement. I'm not sure what you mean, should <%= f.simple_fields_for(:practitioners) do |p| %> be <%= f.simple_fields_for(:practitioners_attributes) do |p| %> ?? I'm new to rails and programming, so I'm trying to learn :-)

Comment: Yes, try changing to `f.simple_fields_for(:practitioners_attributes)`. See the last part of my answer.

Comment: Then I get this error 'ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in RegistrationStepsController#update' 'unknown attribute 'practitioners_attributes' for User.
'

Comment: Then leave `<%= f.simple_fields_for(:practitioners) do |p| %>` and change your permit to `practitioners` instead of `practitioners_attributes`.

Comment: Oh, right. Look at the error. `accepts_nested_attributes_for :practitioners` is defined in `Clinic`, not `User`.

Comment: So it should only be defined in User and not Clinic? Or should it be defined in both?

Comment: What do you think? Look at how you've defined your associations.

Comment: only user I guess, my head is spinning around to understand all of this

Answer (score 0):

Change

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord    
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :practitioners, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

    has_many :clinics, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :clinics, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**clinic.rb**

```
class Clinic < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :practitioners
end
```

**practitioner.rb**

```
class Practitioner < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to: clinic
end
```

TO

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :clinics, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clinics, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    end
```

**clinic.rb**

```
class Clinic < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :practitioners
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :practitioners, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    end
```

**practitioner.rb**

```
class Practitioner < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to: clinic
end
```

The reason being you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for the models that are `has_many` in current model.

So user should accept params for `clinics`, and `clinics` should accept params for `practitioners`.

*Update*

You should not be using this

```
<div class="content">
<div class="content practitioner">
<h2 class="page-title">Generel information</h2>

<%= simple_form_for @user, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>

<%= f.simple_fields_for(:clinics) do |p| %>
<%= render 'clinics/clinics_fields', :f => p %>
<% end %>
</div>
<div class="submit-container">
<%= f.submit "Gem", :class => 'btn blue' %>

</div>
<% end %>

</div>
```

It should be something like

***practitioners_general.html.rb***

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content practitioner">
        <h2 class="page-title">Generel information</h2>
        <%= simple_form_for @user, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>
            <%= f.simple_fields_for(:clinics) do |p| %>
                <%= render 'clinics/clinics_fields', :f => p %>
            <% end %>
            <div class="submit-container">
                <%= f.submit "Gem", :class => 'btn blue' %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

***_clinics_fields.html.rb***

```
            <%= f.simple_fields_for(:practitioners) do |p| %>
                <%= render 'practitioners/practitioners_fields', :f => p %>
            <% end %>
```

***_practitioners_fields.html.rb***

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="basic-section">
  ...
  ...
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to understand the concept better how nested params work

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user)
        .permit(
          ...user attributes related params
          clinics_attributes: [
            ...clinics attributes related params
            practitioners_attributes: [
              ...practitioner attributes related params
            ]
          ])
end
```

`clinics_attributes` should be a part of `user_params` since `clinic` belongs to user. Similarly `practitioners_attributes` will be part of `clinic_params`

Comment: But then I get this error ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in RegistrationStepsController#update unknown attribute 'practitioners_attributes' for User.

Comment: I've updated the question with the changes you've proposed and also with the error I'm getting now

Comment: but then I get the Unpermitted parameter error again, please look at the updated question with the updated code and error